# first `readLine` is skipped inside a `case - of` control flow in Nim-lang

Tags: while-loop, nim-lang

I have the following code.

```
import lib

var stat = false

when isMainModule:
  while stat != true:
    echo("Option: ")
    var opt = readChar(stdin)
    case opt
      of 'q':
        stat = true
      of 'n':
        echo("Salu: ")
        var ss = readLine(stdin)
        echo("Nam: ")
        var nn = readLine(stdin)
        let k = prompt("Rust")
      else: discard
```

What I am trying to achieve is, prompting and receiving user input one after another for two variables. Upon choosing `n` I am expecting `Salu` first and once user input is supplied then `Nam`.

However, what I receive when I execute the following `nim` code by issuing the following command is, `nim c -r src/mycode.nim`

```
~~> nim c -r src/cmdparsing.nim
...
...
...
CC: stdlib_system.nim
CC: cmdparsing.nim
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: operation successful (48441 lines compiled; 2.338 sec total; 66.824MiB peakmem; Debug Build) [SuccessX]
Hint: /home/XXXXX/Development/nim_devel/mycode/src/mycode  [Exec]
Option: 
n
Salu: 
Nam:
```

`Salu` is being echoed, but `readLine` doesn't wait for my input and immediately echoes `Nam`. But, stacked `readLine` commands from the `prompt` procedure appears one after the other for receiving user input.

I was wondering what is that I am missing to understand here. Could someone enlighten me?

Code for `prompt` lives in `lib.nim` which is as follows,

```
proc prompt*(name: string): bool =
  echo("Salutation: ")
  var nn = readLine(stdin)
  echo(nn&"."&name)
  echo("Diesel")
  var dd = readLine(stdin)
  echo(dd)
  return true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a `readChar` to get the opt value, and then you input two chars: `n` and `\n`. The first is the opt value, the second gets *buffered* or retained in the `stdin` waiting for further reading. The next time you try to read a line, the `\n` that's still hanging is interpreted as a new line, and immediately assigned to `ss`. You don't see anything because the line is empty except for the newline char.

E.g.

```
var opt = readChar(stdin)

case opt
of 'n':
  var ss = readLine(stdin)
  echo ss
else:
  discard
```

Compile and run, but in the input write something like "ntest". `n` fires the first branch of `case`, `test` (the remainder of `stdin`) is assigned to `ss`, and echoed.

You have two options to solve the problem:

1. Read a line instead of a char, and store only the first char with something like `var opt = readLine(stdin)[0]`.
2. Use the [rdstdin](https://nim-lang.org/docs/rdstdin.html) module:

   ```
   import rdstdin

   var ss = readLineFromStdin("Salu:")
   ```